# Prove $\sup\{x_n,x_{n+1},\ldots\}$ converges if $x_n$ bounded

Tags: real-analysis

I want to prove that $\sup\{x_n,x_{n+1},\ldots\}$ converges if $\{x_n\}$ bounded. My plan is to prove it is bounded and is monotone. Since any subsequence is bounded the supremums will be bounded. I am not sure how to proceed. So $y_1$ is the supremum of $\{x_1,x_2,\ldots\}$ and $y_2$ of $\{x_2,x_3,\ldots\}$ but I don't know anything about the relation between $x_1$ and $x_2$.

Comment: You are on the right track. I am guessing that these are Real numbers we are talking about?

Comment: Can you show that if $A\subset B$, then $\sup(A)\geq \sup (B)$? That is all you need to see that the sups are weakly decreasing.

Comment: @Juanito I assume you mean $A \supset B$?

Comment: yea, the next ineq should be reversed  :)

Answer (score 1):

Assume $|x_n|\leq M $.

Put $$u_n=\sup(x_n,x_{n+1},...) $$

it is quite clear that

$$|u_n|\leq M $$ and

$$ u_n \geq \sup(x_{n+1},x_{n+2},...) $$

which means that $(u_n) $ is decreasing.

As a bounded decreasing sequence, $(u_n) $ is convergent.